# Four questions about "Nicht umsonst nennt man es »klassisch«"

Tags: word-choice, sentence-structure, personal-pronoun

I heard this sentence from a non-native speaker, I got the meaning but I have several reservations about the grammar and words used:

> Musik von Beethoven und Mozart ist heutzutage sehr beliebt. Nicht umsonst nennt man es »klassisch«, da es noch viele Jahrzehnte aktuell bleiben kann.

My questions are:

1. Shouldn't it be "sie" instead of "es"?

> Musik von Beethoven und Mozart ist heutzutage sehr beliebt. Nicht umsonst nennt man **sie** »klassisch«, da **sie** noch viele Jahrzehnte aktuell bleiben kann.

2. Can I use "nicht von ungefähr" instead of "nicht umsonst"?

> Musik von Beethoven und Mozart ist heutzutage sehr beliebt. **Nicht von ungefähr** nennt man es »klassisch«, da es noch viele Jahrzehnte aktuell bleiben kann.

3. Can I put "klassische Musik" instead of "klassisch"?

> Musik von Beethoven und Mozart ist heutzutage sehr beliebt. Nicht umsonst nennt man es »**klassische Musik**«, da es noch viele Jahrzehnte aktuell bleiben kann.

4. If I wanted to change the last part, can I say something like:

> Musik von Beethoven und Mozart ist heutzutage sehr beliebt. Nicht umsonst nennt man es »klassisch«, da es (seit?) viele Jahrzehnte populär bleiben hat.

Answer (score 4):

> Shouldn't it be "sie" instead of "es"?

Yes, you're completely right.

> Can I use "nicht von ungefähr" instead of "nicht umsonst"?

Yes, absolutely, that is a nice way of saying it.

> Can I put "klassische Musik" instead of "klassisch"?

Yes, if you're not bothered by the repetition if the word "music", you can say that.

> If I wanted to change the last part, can I say something like:
> ... da es (seit?) viele Jahrzehnte populär bleiben hat.

I assume you mean "since it's stayed popular for many decades"?

The German *Perfekt* tense of the verb *bleiben* would be "... geblieben ist"

> da sie (jetzt schon) viele Jahrzehnte populär geblieben ist.

Alternatively, you could just use present tense without "bleiben":

> da sie (jetzt schon) seit vielen Jahrzehnten populär ist.

(Offtopic: and of course that's not the reason why Beethoven's und Mozart's compositions are called "klassisch". It rather refers to the epoch in musical history to which they are counted: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_Klassik
)

Comment: Many thanks to you!! Are "nicht umsonst" & "nicht von ungefähr" always interchangeable?? Also, regarding the 4th question, why did you use "seit" with the present tense but not with the perfect tense? 
Shouldn't it be the other way around? Can I say, for example: »da sie (jetzt schon) "seit" viele Jahrzehnte populär geblieben ist« ??

Comment: @KeNSmilePachI: "nicht umsonst" and "nicht von ungefähr" are *somewhat* interchangeable. "Nicht umsonst" here means "not without cause" and used in this way it is interchangeable, but can also mean "not for free" ("Das ist nicht umsonst" "This is not free of charge" - umsonst=gratis=free of charge). To make matters worse "umsonst" has actually two distinct meanings - "for free" and "in vain" - there is a joke: "meine Schule war gratis, deine umsonst".

Comment: With "bleiben", I wouldn't use "seit" with a time span, but rather "über" or "für" or just a nominative like here. I would use "seit" with "bleiben" only with a starting point in time, like "Die Musik der Beatles ist seit den 1960er-Jahren (immer) populär geblieben."  With "sein" however, I have no problem using "seit" with either a time span or a starting point. I don't really know why it is that way.